# Cannot install Windows 7 after Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: multi-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP 2000-2100 laptop. Now I want to install Windows 7, and set up a dual boot.

I have created a bootable device for Windows 7, and also created a separate partition in NTFS format for installing it. But Windows is not installing on that partition.

I receive an error message on the windows installation screen. I have Ubuntu 16.04 on Disk 0 Partition 1, and was trying to install windows on Disk 0 Partition 2. I also have flagged it as boot using GParted. But still it is not working.

[image]

Comment: What error are you receiving when you attempt to install?

Comment: @MrStatic : The error message I'm receiving is in this image- http://i.stack.imgur.com/vDLvC.jpg

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Hi @AndroidDev, yes, your answer worked. You're really awesome!! Thanks a ton for taking out time to help me. I wish I could return your favor in some ways. Thanks again man..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Please read though all of the steps before doing this!

## Warning: Any data on your HDD will be toast after step #3.

1) Boot the Windows 7 install media

2) On the initial screen it drops you at, **instead of** clicking continue, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, which will open a Command prompt.

3) In the command prompt, run:

```
diskpart
list disk       #Look to see which number is your main HDD. (Usually 0)
select disk 0   #Replace with your number from the above command
clean
exit
```

Then close out of the command prompt.

4) Now, continue with the Windows install as usual.

5) After Windows is completely installed and you land on the desktop, install all of your hardware drivers.

6) Next, in the start menu, **right**-click on the "Computer" header on the right side bar, and select "Manage".

7) After it loads, change to the Disk Management section (header on the left side) and shrink the partition you installed Windows to by however much you want to leave for Ubuntu. **Leave it unallocated**

8) After doing the above, boot from your Ubuntu installation media.

9) Tell Ubuntu to "Install alongside Windows 7". It will automatically install to the unallocated space you created in step #7.

10) Reboot, and with any luck, you'll see GRUB, giving you a choice of either Windows 7 or Ubuntu

Since you're new here, I'll just let you know that if my answer worked for you, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.